# FileHandle get the undefined when I drag and drop multiple files to the browser at once

Tags: javascript

```
async function handleDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const handles = []
  const dataTransferItems = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.items)
  const firstHandle = await dataTransferItems[0].getAsFileSystemHandle()
  const secondHandle = await dataTransferItems[1].getAsFileSystemHandle()
  console.log(firstHandle, 'firstHandle')
}
```

For example, if I drag and drop two files into the browser at the same time and then get the dataTransferItemList via dataTransfer.items, then I want to get the fileHandle of each item in the list via getAsFileSystemHandle(), At present, the problem is that my firstHandle has received the value, but secondHandle is undefined.
I hope you can tell me why I get undefined, thanks

I just want to get the fileHandle of the file that I drag and drop, or do you have another way

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me too.. it's strange behavior.. try this:

```
let files = [];
let folders = [];
let promises = [];
if (event.dataTransfer.items) {
    for (const item of [...event.dataTransfer.items]) {
        promises.push(item.getAsFileSystemHandle().then(
            async function (item) {
                await onFileDropProcessEntry(item, folders, files);
            }
        ));
    }
}
for (const promise of [...promises]) {
    await promise;
}



async function onFileDropProcessEntry(entry, folders, files) {
    if (entry.kind === 'directory') {
        let folderFile = [];
        let folder = {name: entry.name};
        for await (const [key, value] of entry.entries()) {
            folderFile.push(await value.getFile());
        }
        folder.files = folderFile;
        folders.push(folder);
    } else {
        if (item.getAsFile().size <= glConfig.attachMaxFileSize) {
            files.push(item.getAsFile());
        } else {
            let err = "File troppo grande : " + item.getAsFile().name + ", dim.: " + item.getAsFile().size + ", max:" + glConfig.attachMaxFileSize
            console.error(err);
            Liquid.showToast("iArt", err, "error");
        }
    }
}
```